# Laravel Inserting nested Eloquent ORM model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have three tables with relationships like below:

1. *product*

   ```
   has many options
   ```
2. *option*

   ```
   can belong to many product
   has option_values
   ```
3. *option_value*

   ```
   belongs to many option
   ```

Using Laravel I can update *option* like this

```
product->options()->insert($stuff);
```

However I want to insert into the *option_value* as well.

I tried

```
product->options()->values()->insert($otherStuff);
```

But that doesnt work. How can this be done with Eloquent ORM?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a sub-relationship this way, you have to actually have the model result and call the method on it, or use eager loading but eager loading does not help with an insert.

You would have to loop the option models and insert trough them, but that results in way too many insert queries. Better may be to just grab the related ids and run the insert in a single fluent query instead of many Eloquent.

```php
$option_ids = $product->options()->lists('id');
DB::table(OptionValue::$table)->insert(array_merge($data, $option_ids));
```